# How to import NodeSet.xml into .net opc ua server

Tags: .net, opc-ua, opc, .net-8.0

I am currently working on a personal project where I want to use an external Nodeset into my Opc Ua Server build within .NET 8

I am currently stuck to resolve a problem with the Import of the Xml containing the Nodeset information about `DI` specification [OPC 10000-100: Devices](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/DI/v102/docs/5.9)

As described from spec. the node `DeviceSet` should be visible (automatically) from any Opc Ua Viewer under the `Objects` folder...but it's not happening.

Here below my custom node manager with the import method

**MainNodeManager.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Opc.Ua;
using Opc.Ua.Export;
using Opc.Ua.Server;
using System.Reflection;
using OpcUaServerSample.Host.OPCUA;

namespace OpcUaServerSample.Host.NodeManagers
{
    public class MainNodeManager : CustomNodeManager2
    {
        private IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> m_externalReferences;
        private ILogger _logger;
        private OpcUaServerConfiguration m_configuration;
        private static readonly string[] ModelNamespaceUris = new string[]
        {
            OPCUA.Namespaces.OpcUaServer
        };

        public MainNodeManager(ILogger logger, IServerInternal server, ApplicationConfiguration configuration)
            : base(server, ModelNamespaceUris)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            SystemContext.NodeIdFactory = this;

            // get the configuration for the node manager.
            m_configuration = configuration.ParseExtension<OpcUaServerConfiguration>() ?? new();
        }

        public override void CreateAddressSpace(IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences)
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                m_externalReferences = externalReferences;

                IList<IReference> references = null;

                if (!externalReferences.TryGetValue(ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, out references))
                {
                    externalReferences[ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder] = references = new List<IReference>();
                }

                try
                {
                    ImportXml(externalReferences, "NodeSets\\Opc.Ua.Di.NodeSet2.xml");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Something went wrong on import NodeSets", ex);
                }

                NodeState deviceSetNode = PredefinedNodes.Values.First(x => x.BrowseName.Name == "DeviceSet");

                base.CreateAddressSpace(externalReferences);
            }
        }

        private void ImportXml(IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences, string resourcepath)
        {
            try
            {
                
                NodeStateCollection predefinedNodes = new NodeStateCollection();

                Stream stream = new FileStream(resourcepath, FileMode.Open);
                UANodeSet nodeSet = UANodeSet.Read(stream);

                foreach (string namespaceUri in nodeSet.NamespaceUris)
                {
                    SystemContext.NamespaceUris.GetIndexOrAppend(namespaceUri);
                }
                nodeSet.Import(SystemContext, predefinedNodes);

                for (int ii = 0; ii < predefinedNodes.Count; ii++)
                {
                    AddPredefinedNode(SystemContext, predefinedNodes[ii]);
                }
                // ensure the reverse refernces exist.
                AddReverseReferences(externalReferences);

                _logger.LogInformation($"NodeSet {nodeSet.NamespaceUris[0]} imported");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("NodeSetImportNodeManager.Import: Error loading node set", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Opc Ua view

[image]

**What I tried**

- Search for any information about import
- Search for sample

**What I Expected**

- See `DeviceSet` node under `Objects` folder